# How can I lose a bounty?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Is it possible to shake off a bounty in GTA Online?

If so, how?

Comment: Its from an NPC though lol im in an invite only room lol

Comment: Get in a [chopper](http://i.imgur.com/BOE3Bvj.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bounties can be put on you by other players or sometimes by NPC's if you steal their car. If nobody kills you after one full in-game day (48 minutes real time), the bounty will expire and you receive the cash. There's even an [achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a179422/run-like-the-wind-achievement.htm) to do this.

Spending time in LS Customs does not count toward the 48 minutes. You are best off hiding in your garage or a remote location if playing in a public game. Or if you really want to shake it without the heat, just play in a private game for a while and it will go away once time is up.

Answer (score 2):

"You can only place bounties on people level 10 or above.

Bounties stick to you until they're claimed or until you survive for 30 minutes, after that you get to keep the money from the bounty.

It is possible that an Npc May put a bounty on you for stealing their car or killing a friend/member of their gang. I believe all odd denominations of thousands of dollars are bounties placed by npcs, ($1000, $3000, $5000, $7000)

Bounties also transfer across lobbies until they are collected, my best advice is to have a friend or crew member so that at least someone in your circle benefits. I received a $9000 bounty and requested my friend shoot my in the head after I had one last smoke. "

That's what I found.

The link [here](http://gtaforums.com/topic/611462-how-does-the-bounty-system-of-gta-5-online-work/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm running from a $9000 one right now.  I suggest jumping on a train in private, seeing as NPCs are too dumb to get on one.  Also, press R1/RB to lay low.  But make sure you don't idle too long, or you'll get kicked for it.

Comment: If a NPC kills you, they do not claim the bounty (only another player can); you can die endless times by a NPC and still claim the bounty - I did it last night :-D.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait out the 48 minutes, I would suggest going into a private lobby with a friend and having them shoot you. Then you guys can split the bounty 50/50.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide/wait it out. The hospital bill makes the 50/50 split a non-starter for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just to let a crew member or friend kill you and split the bounty. If you don't have any, don't hide, but take your chances. I never saw a bounty higher than $9000 and if you have to wait 30 or 48 minutes, then it's not beneficial, because there are a lot of other ways to make even more money in the same amount of time. Even stealing a car and sell it to LS customs gives you more money and it only takes a few minutes or even less than a minute. Hiding from bounty is a waste of time. I have a bounty right now and I'm not hiding. I'm just doing missions and ignoring it and guess what? In less than 2 minutes I get the money for the bounty!

Comment: bounty is from $1,000 to $9,000

Answer (score 0):

I like to take a chopper and fly around. It
Is funny watching all the people chase you. So far it works for me.